# Redis vs Appfabric Cache , Or another solution

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I am planning use cache mechanism for meta data of realtime datas.
I will use in 2 or more different application.

Get performance very important for me instead of set performance.
I'm undecided which technology should I use, Redis on Windows or Appfabric Cache or another solution?

I will store Dictionary, then I will query from key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hard researched all of day. I decided [Couchbase Memcached](http://www.couchbase.com/memcached)
Its really ready to enterprise and very fast.

Answer (score -1):

Opting for either of it depends what type of data it will b working on ... Found a [link](http://siliconangle.com/blog/2012/02/27/redis-on-windows-vs-microsofts-appfabric/) that could help